# Blank screen is displayed - React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I wrote a simple React Native app which shall display four colored rectangles. The app runs well but app is showing only a blank white screen. I replaced the content of the render function with just a text, that is displayed properly. What is going wrong?

Code provided below:

**index.android.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Mainscreen from './components/screens/mainscreen.js';


 class styling extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
<View>
<Mainscreen />
</View>
);

  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('styling', () => styling);
```

**Mainscreen.js:**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet}  from 'react-native';

export default class Mainscreen extends Component{
  render(){
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<View style={styles.smallContainer}>
  <View style={styles.above}>
    <View style={styles.leftAbove}></View>
    <View style={styles.rightAbove}></View>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.bottom}>
    <View style={styles.leftBottom}></View>
    <View style={styles.rightBottom}></View>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
);
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    flexDirection:'column'
  },
  above:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginRight: 10
  },
  bottom:
  {
      flex:1,
      flexDirection:'row',
      marginTop: 10,
      marginLeft: 10,
      marginBottom: 10,
      marginRight: 10
  },
leftAbove:{
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  flex: 0.6,
},
rightAbove:{
backgroundColor: 'red',
flex: 0.4,
},
leftBottom:{
backgroundColor: 'blue',
flex: 0.4,
},
rightBottom:{
backgroundColor: 'yellow',
flex: 0.6,
},
smallContainer:{
  flex:1,
  padding: 10,
  backgroundColor:'black'
}
});
```

Comment: why are you using ".js" in your import statement? Also If your file name is MainScreen.js (assuming that your file name is with capital M) then your import statement should be like: import Mainscreen from './components/screens/Mainscreen'; Also I am assuming that path to the file you are importing is correct.

Comment: Yeah I am using the correct path. its Mainscreen class in mainscreen.js. I tried replacing the entire "View" with a Text and that is displayed properly. The problem is with the nested Views itself. @Ankit Aggarwal

Comment: There is some issue with styling. Remove flex: 1 from following: "container", "smallContainer", "above" and "bottom" styles. Also, give some height to "above" and "below" styles. That will work. Will try to find the reason

Comment: Yeah. I made some changes in styling and it worked out. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give **flex: 1** to your View in styling component (everything else is fine) as follows:

```
class styling extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Mainscreen />
            </View>
        );

    }
}
```

notice the style of **flex: 1** in top level view component. It is necessary to tell the view to take the *full-screen width and height*. Otherwise, *height and width will be 0*.

Comment: Yeah I get your point, but I did that already. Instead used styling separately rather than inline.

Comment: great :). If this answer is correct, could you mark it accepted to help others having same issue.

Comment: Please tell the reason for the downvote, so that answer can be improved. Marking it not useful may not help others.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I wondered why my View Component was white and not rendering stuff inside. This solved it. :D